# Inserting data in diferent tables

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to add data to diferent tables in MySQL, but at the moment of run my code, it shows me a error is it "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query()", is the firs time that y use the query function so I don't know whats going wrong.

```
     <?php  
session_start();

$_SESSION['ID_user'];
$id = $_SESSION['ID_user'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 


    if($name == "" && $password == "" && $company == "" ){
        return false;
    }
    else {
    require './conectar.php';
    $resultset = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID_user = '$id' LIMIT 1");
    $resultset->execute();
    $resultkey = $resultset->fetch();

    if($resultkey !== false) {

        $update = "UPDATE user SET Name_user='$name', password='$password' WHERE ID_user = '$id' LIMIT 1";
        $up = $conn->prepare($update);
        $up->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $up->execute();
        $result = $up->fetch();
        $_SESSION['Name_user'] = $result['name'];

        $lastid = $conn->query("SELECT last_insert_id()")->fetch();

        $insert = "INSERT INTO rel_company_user (ID_user)  VALUES ('$id')";
        $in = $conn->prepare($insert);
        $in->execute();


        $insert = "INSERT INTO company (Name_company) VALUES ('$company')";
        $in = $conn->prepare($insert);
        $in->execute();


        $update = "UPDATE rel_company_user SET ID_company='$lastid' WHERE ID_user = '$id' LIMIT 1";
        $up = $conn->prepare($update);
        $up->execute();

    }

}

header('Location: http://seth.com/dashboard?ftime=1');


/* Pedir el id y actualizarlo */


?>
```

Comment: You should use parameters in your prepared queries, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Where do you set `$thelast`? Also, the `global` statement is only needed inside functions.

Comment: It should be `$conn->query`, not `$thelast->query`

Comment: You have no `:name` placeholder in the `UPDATE` query, you can't use `bindParam()` with it.

Comment: If the user ID isn't in the `user` table yet, how does `$_SESSION['ID_user']` get set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I insert data in related tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066414/how-can-i-insert-data-in-related-tables)

Comment: @Barmar  ok, I changed it and now it works but it doesn't insert data on the rel_company_user table, about the parameter ¿do you have an example?

Comment: @Barmar ID_user is created in a back step, but exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should use parameters in all your queries. And you can't use `bindParam()` if you didn't put a placeholder in the query.
2. FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS is not a valid argument to `bindParam()`. The third argument is an optional data type.
3. You never set `$thelast` anywhere, that should be `$conn`.
4. If `$id` is already assigned, you can't use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get `ID_user`. Just insert that value into the `user` table.
5. You don't need to perform a query to get the last insert ID. Just use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the `VALUES` list of the next `INSERT` query.
6. You can't fetch the results of an `UPDATE` query.
7. You can't get the last insert ID if you haven't done an insert. The `UPDATE user` query should be `INSERT INTO user`.
8. In several places you assigned the SQL to `$insert`, but then did `$conn->prepare($update)`.

```
<?php  
session_start();

$id = $_SESSION['ID_user'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 


if($name == "" && $password == "" && $company == "" ){
    return false;
}
else {
    require './conectar.php';
    $resultset = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID_user = :id LIMIT 1");
    $resultset->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $resultset->execute();
    $resultkey = $resultset->fetch();

    if($resultkey !== false) {

        $update = "INSERT INTO user (ID_user, Name_user, password) VALUES (:id, :name, :password)";
        $up = $conn->prepare($update);
        $up->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $up->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $up->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $up->execute();
        $result = $up->fetch();
        $_SESSION['Name_user'] = $name;

        $insert = "INSERT INTO rel_company_user (ID_user)  VALUES (:id)";
        $in = $conn->prepare($insert);
        $in->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $in->execute();

        $insert = "INSERT INTO company (Name_company) VALUES (:company)";
        $in = $conn->prepare($insert);
        $in->bindParam(':company', $company);
        $in->execute();

        $update = "INSERT INTO rel_company_user (ID_company, ID_user) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), :id)";
        $up = $conn->prepare($update);
        $up->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $up->execute();

    }

}

header('Location: http://seth.com/dashboard?ftime=1');

/* Pedir el id y actualizarlo */
?>
```

Comment: Great, much better than my code xD(thank you for take time for it). I changed the firs insert for an UPDATE, but I have the next error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on string in completedetails.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in completedetails.php on line 34

Comment: I had a typo: `$id->bindParam` should be `$in->bindParam`

Comment: you are right, thank you so much, I learned of you,